# Strapi filtering does not work when I provide JWT token and returns everything

Tags: python-3.x, django, strapi

I have this Strapi endpoint that return the products.

The problem is when I include the jwt token in the headers the filtering dose not work and it returns every thing,
but when I take the jwt suddenly the filtering works.

This is the function:

```py
def get_products_by_supplier(jwt, supplier_id):
    url = f"{STRAPI_BASE_URL}/products?populate=*&filters[supplier][id][$eq]={supplier_id}"
    if jwt:
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {jwt}",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return response.json()
        else:
            return None
    else:
        return None
```

How can I solve this issue because I need to use the jwt token in the headers?